# Is it possible for moderators to earn the Reviewer badge?

Tags: discussion, support, review-badges

I hit the 1000 reviews mark several days ago and still don't have the [Reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1478/reviewer) badge.

(I saw that two of the new mods already have the badge, but they earned it before being elected.)

Comment: The only "actions" that are counted towards the badge are those done while on the /review page.  You can check the numbers in the "Your Review Stats" box on that page.

Comment: @chown Ah, I think there might be two problems.  I see a different view when I go to /review on SO than on other sites, and I didn't quite know exactly what "actioned" really meant.  Thanks.

Comment: @Bill: Also, multiple actions on one post don't count, only one per post.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, Moderators can earn the Reviewer badge.

I have it over on [Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/5095/barry?tab=badges) where I have been a moderator since Feb 2011.

A post becomes "reviewed" if you click "review post" or the hyperlink from the /review page. You can act on it anywhere after that.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFFUs.jpg]

Comment: Thanks.  It turns out I was working from an incomplete understanding of what "actioned" means.  It's probably obvious to anyone paying attention, but for anyone else wondering, you have to take actions *from the /review page* or they don't count.

Comment: @bill not true, a post becomes "reviewed" if you click "review post" or the hyperlink from the /review page.  You can act on it anywhere after that

Comment: @waffles Thanks for that clarification.